# How to check text typeface style in Android Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

On our application, we have a login button that has the text "LOGIN".

When I run the following test, it fails:

[image]

It fails because "LOGIN" doesn't match "Login"

[image]

The mText is "Login" even though it displays as "LOGIN" on the button itself.  I assume that this is the typefaceStyle that makes it all in caps?  If so, can someone tell me how I can verify that the correct typeface style is being used?
Or..how can I pull the text as it is actually displayed on the screen for comparison?

Comment: "I assume that this is the typefaceStyle that makes it all in caps?" -- yes. By default, Material Design calls for all-caps on button captions, so they apply that at the theme level, both for `Theme.Material`- and `Theme.AppCompat`-based themes.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following matcher to check whether the text is capitalized :

```
public static Matcher<View> withTransformedText(final String text) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView.class) {
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(TextView textView) {
            final TransformationMethod transformationMethod = textView.getTransformationMethod();
            final String transformedText = transformationMethod.getTransformation(textView.getText(), textView).toString();
            return text.equals(transformedText);
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with transformed text: " + text);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, If we use default theme as per new version then it's show button text as UPPER case but you can use **textAllCaps** option to enable or disable it. Please refer given snap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw4wo.png)

Comment: The question is for how to create the test/matcher in espresso to verify that the text is capitalized (has correct typeface style)